# Restrict Rest API call from Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: rest, nginx

I am using Nginx reverse proxy to access an API between server and client

I want to restrict certain api call from nginx api

For example:

Server has following rest API: 
/api/foo
/api/bar

I want client to only access foo and not bar. Is there a way to restrict it from nginx proxy

Comment: From maintainability and security perspective it sounds as if that restriction should be in the API server and not in the reverse proxy. Or you should _whitelist_ each command you want to allow.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to restrict certain api call from nginx api

Just return "Not found" (404) or "Forbidden" (403)

```
location /api/bar {
  return 403;
}
```

Comment: for 1 API make sense to return 403 or 404 but if I have 50 API's then what to do, I cannot add this config for each api. For eg: if I have 100 API out of which I want to allow 10 and restrict 90 then what to do ?

Comment: Use namespacing, for example like this: `/api/foo` `/api/private/bar`. Configure restriction for private namespace `location /private/bar { return 404; }`